# How do I change a display plugin class

Tags: 8, views, hooks

I'm attempting to modify the definition of a view display plugin to use my own custom class. I used `hook_views_plugins_display_alter()`, but it doesn't seem it's invoked at all. I've searched in core code where the hook is invoked, but I didn't find it.

Does anyone know an example of using this hook, or another way to override the class for a view display plugin?

Comment: Found this example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219835/add-background-image-to-block-from-view. The hook is invoked when you clear the cache.

Comment: @4k4 thank you, that was exactly what I needed. How do I accept your answer?